# Laravel blade image display

Tags: php, laravel

can someone help me with image display in laravel blade?

So this is full image URL after upload

```
http://webshop.local/uploads/products/1592949903recommend.png
```

It is supposed to be uploaded to

`public/uploads/products`
folder.

Here is part of code where I create product (ProductsController):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'productImage' => 'required|image'
        ]);

        $productImage = $request->productImage;

        $productImage_new_name = time() . $productImage->getClientOriginalName();

        $productImage->move('uploads/products' . $productImage_new_name);

        Product::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'productImage' => '/uploads/products/' . $productImage_new_name,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'description' => $request->description
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('products.index');
    }
```

Also here is blade display:

```
<th><img src="{{ $product->productImage }}" alt="{{ $product->title }} image"></th>
```

And this is getting me right link because of:

```
public function getProductImageAttribute($productImage){
        return asset($productImage);
    }
```

in product model.

**EDIT**
When I upload new image it does not go into folder instead it just create new folder with the name of the image and inside it is file with name `phpSOMETHING_RANDOM_HERE.tmp`

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine it is doing same thing as my model. :)

Comment: @Saed Silajdzic sorry I misread the product model.

Comment: Did you check that the image is in the folder /uploads/products/?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: $productImage->move(public_path('uploads/products' . $productImage_new_name));

Comment: @Don'tPanic The first sentence described the problem. I have a good image URL after uploading it but the image is not displayed. Now I am asking does anyone know why and how to fix it.

Comment: @ItamarGarcia seems like it does not go into the folder. Instead, it create a new folder with the name of the image and inside that folder is .tmp file

https://prnt.sc/t5h2jy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else faces this problem please check this part of your code.

```
$productImage = $request->productImage;
$productImage_new_name = time() . $productImage->getClientOriginalName();
$productImage->move('uploads/products', $productImage_new_name);
```

Specifically this line:

```
$productImage->move('uploads/products', $productImage_new_name);
```

The whole time **I had dot between path and variable for the name of an uploaded file**.

*So to fix this problem just change dot for coma.*

Instead of

```
$productImage->move('uploads/products' . $productImage_new_name);
```

You need

```
$productImage->move('uploads/products', $productImage_new_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your store method

```
$path = $request->productImage->store('uploads/products');
// OR if you need to give it name
$path = $request->productImage->storeAs('uploads/products', 'filename.jpg');
```

You can `'productImage' => $path,` while creating product.

Comment: Thank you, meanwhile, I found what caused all this :) It was just dot at the wrong place. I commented under, you can check it out.